Shorter proof of an example of a $\sigma$-algebra
In almost every book on probability and measure theory, when you see $\sigma$-algebras and measurable space, you can find the next example
Example. Let $\Omega$ be a set, let $S$ be a subset of $\Omega$ and let $\mathcal{F}$ be the set of subsets of $\Omega$ defined by $\mathcal{F}=\{\emptyset, S,S^\complement, \Omega\}$. Then $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$.
Yes, you can find this example in almost every book on such subjects, but not a proof of the statement. What do we have to prove? Well, we have to prove that $\Omega\in\mathcal{F}$, but that's given by how we define $\mathcal{F}$, we also have to prove that $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under complements, i.e. for every element $A\in\mathcal{F}$ it holds that $A^\complement:=\Omega\setminus A\in\mathcal{F}$. Let's prove it:
Let $A\in\mathcal{F}$, then, by how we define $\mathcal{F}$, it follows that $A=\emptyset$ o $A=S$ o $A=S^\complement$ o $A=\Omega$, thence $A^\complement=\Omega$ o $A^\complement=S^\complement$ o $A^\complement=S$ o $A^\complement=\emptyset$, hence, by how we define $\mathcal{F}$, we have that $A^\complement\in\mathcal{F}$.
Therefore, $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under complements, now, to prove that $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra we must prove that $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under countable unions, i.e. for every sequence $A$ on $\mathcal{F}$ it holds that $\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j\in\mathcal{F}$. Here is where it gets rude, I have a proof of this last property, but it is large. I use the next results:
Result 1. $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under pairwise unions, i.e. for all elements $A,B\in\mathcal{F}$ it holds that $A\cup B\in\mathcal{F}$, if and only if $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under finite unions, i.e. for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and all $A_1,...,A_n\in\mathcal{F}$ it holds that $\bigcup_{j=1}^n A_j\in\mathcal{F}$.
Result 2. If a set of subsets $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under finite unions, then it satisfies Property 3 of a $\sigma$-algebra if and only if for every non-decreasing sequence $A$ on $\mathcal{A}$ we have that $\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j\in\mathcal{A}$
By a non-decreasing sequence $A$ on $\mathcal{A}$ I mean $A:\mathbb{N}\to\mathcal{A}$ such that $A_n\subseteq A_{n+1}$ for all $n$.
To prove that $\mathcal{F}$ satisfies Property 3 of a $\sigma$-algebra, we first prove that it is closed under pairwise unions, we can do this: Let $A,B\in\mathcal{F}$, then we have one of the next cases

hence we have one of the next cases

In any case, we conclude that $A\cup B\in\mathcal{F}$. Therefore $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under pairwise unions, then, by Result 1, we have that $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under finite unions, so we can use Result 2 to prove that $\mathcal{F}$ satisfies Property 3 of a $\sigma$-algebra. The proof is by cases, let $A$ be a non-decreasing sequence on $\mathcal{F}$
Case 1. If there exits $j\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $A_j=\emptyset$, then, because $A$ is not decreasing, it follows that $A_j=\emptyset$ for every $j\in\mathbb{N}$, hence  $\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j=\emptyset\in\mathcal{F}$.
Case 2. If there exists $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $A_k=\Omega$, then, because $A$ is non-decreasing, it follows that $A_j=\Omega$ for every $j\geq k$, thence $\bigcup_{j=k+1}^\infty A_j=\Omega$, furthermore $\bigcup_{j=1}^k A_j=\Omega$ because $A_k=\Omega$ and because $A_j\subseteq A_k$ for every $j\leq k$, consequently
\begin{align*}
        \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j=\bigcup_{j=1}^k A_j \cup \bigcup_{j=k+1}^\infty A_j=\Omega\cup\Omega=\Omega\in\mathcal{F}.
    \end{align*}
Case 3. Suppose there exists $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $A_k = S$. If $A_j = S$ for all $j > k$, then $\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j = S$. However, if there exists $l \in \mathbb{N}$ with $l > k$ such that $A_l \neq S$, then $A_l = \Omega$ and $A_m = \Omega$ for all $m > l$, so $\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j = \Omega \in \mathcal{F}$.
Case 4. Suppose that for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$ it holds that $A_j \neq \emptyset, S, \Omega$, then for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$ it holds that $A_j = S^\complement$, which implies that $\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j = S^\complement \in \mathcal{F}$.
In any case we conclude that $\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j\in\mathcal{F}$, then $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under non-decreasing unions, thence it satisfies Property 3 of a $\sigma$-algebra. Based on the above, we conclude that $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$.
And THAT WAS THE PROOF, and the reason I am here writing. I wonder if there is a shorter proof, or an alternative way to prove our example, if anyone knows on, please tell me.
Thanks!

You are working much too hard. If a $\sigma$-algebra is finite (as in it has finitely many sets in it) then every increasing sequence of elements is eventually constant, so $\sigma$-additivity is just additivity and you just have to verify that it is a Boolean algebra. The conclusion is that finite $\sigma$-algebras are equivalent to partitions of a set into finitely many disjoint subsets.
